# Using Agora Video Calling Web SDK the createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks does not prompt audio and camera permissions

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, agora.io

Sorry for a dumb explanation and a dumb question.

In the HTML file I link it with the script tag

```
<script
      defer
      type="text/javascript"
      src="javascript/AgoraSDK/AgoraRTC_N-4.13.0.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      defer
      type="text/javascript"
      src="javascript/AgoraSDK/agora-rtm-sdk-1.5.0.js"
    ></script>
```

and when I call the createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks method from Agora Web SDK, the prompt is not showing
`rtc.localTracks = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks();`

back when I call this method on the last day of november, the prompt is still showing.

I did try using navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices method but the chrome is not still showing the audio and camera permission prompt.

On the other browser like for example is firefox the prompt is still showing and not in chrome... I had to manually set the permission in the chrome browser settings.

Now for the question... Is there still a alternative way to prompt access to audio and camera permission in vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure the prompt is shown to users, you can implement a button or some other element that users need to interact with (e.g., click a "Start" button) to trigger the createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks() function. it will create a permission prompt of accessing the audio it worked for me

```
<button id="startButton">Start</button>

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
     const startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
     startButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  try {
     const localTracks = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks();
      // Proceed with using the localTracks (e.g., play video/audio)
  }catch (error) {
       console.error("Error accessing microphone and camera:", error);
    }
  });
});
```